# appending an element to table DOM element using Python xmldoc library

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am using python xmldoc to create node and appending them:

```
codeblocks = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("code")
for ii, codeblock in enumerate(codeblocks):
    if codeblock.getAttribute('class') == 'language-citb':
        codeTable = xmldoc.createElement('table')
        codeTextArea = xmldoc.createElement('textarea')
        codeTable.appendChild(codeTextArea)
        codeblock.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(codeTable,
                                                     codeblock.parentNode)
        #The location of appendChild does not change anything
        #codeTable.appendChild(codeTextArea)
```

orignal dom structure:

```
<pre>
    <code></code>
</pre>
```

expected dom structure:

```
<table>
    <textarea></textarea>
</table>
```

resulting dom structure:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<table></table>
```

why do I get the last DOM structure? I am hoping to get the one before that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the value of textarea by

```
code = xmldoc.createTextNode("SomeValue")
codeTextArea.appendChild(code)
```

to prevent some overflowing of text values
and create 'tr' and 'td' elements inside the table element to make it appear properly.